# How to deploy my web application on the intranet of entreprise

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-deployment

I developed a web application with VS2012 and SqlServer. How can I deploy my application to be accessible from all computers in my company's intranet?

Answer (score 0):

Install Web Deploy on the server then you will be able to publish from Visual Studio directly on the server without doing anything else.

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy